# SQL issue with IN with union

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I cant get In filter to work when using it with Union in subquery.

```
SELECT
    CAST(table1.company_id__c as bigint),
    table1.casenumber
FROM 
    table2
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 ON table2.accountid = table1.id
WHERE
    table1.company_id__c IN (WITH t1 AS
                             (
                                 SELECT
                                     CAST(product_A_ID AS bigint)
                                 FROM
                                     table3
                                 WHERE
                                     filter_1 = 'Yes'
                                     AND product_A_ID IS NOT NULL
                             ),
                             t2 AS 
                             (
                                 SELECT
                                     CAST(product_B_ID AS bigint)
                                 FROM
                                     table3
                                 WHERE
                                     filter_1 = 'Yes'
                                     AND product_B_ID IS NOT NULL
                             ),
                             t3 AS 
                             (
                                 SELECT product_A_ID AS one_ID 
                                 FROM t1
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT product_B_ID AS one_ID 
                                 FROM t2
                             )
                             SELECT * 
                             FROM t3)
    AND table1.country__c = 'UK'
    AND table2.createddate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```

Error message is

> [Code: 500310, SQL State: XX000]  Amazon Invalid operation: Invalid digit, Value 'P', Pos 0, Type: Long
>
> Details:
>
> Error:  Invalid digit, Value 'P', Pos 0, Type: Long
> Code:      1207
> Context:   PYMT-6247719908193229
> Query:     3738401

I can get it to work the the In query is just 1 table (without the union)

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use the WITH statement, simply create a temporary view for the UNION part and SELECT the desired column from that temporary view

```
SELECT
    CAST(table1.company_id__c as bigint),
    table1.casenumber
FROM 
    table2
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 ON table2.accountid = table1.id
WHERE 1=1
    AND table1.country__c = 'UK'
    AND table2.createddate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
    and table1.company_id__c IN (
        select t3.one_id 
        from (
            (SELECT CAST(product_A_ID AS bigint) as one_id FROM table3 WHERE filter_1 = 'Yes' AND product_A_ID IS NOT NULL) 
            union all
            (SELECT CAST(product_B_ID AS bigint) one_id FROM table3 WHERE filter_1 = 'Yes' AND product_B_ID IS NOT NULL)
        ) t3
```

Comment: no luck, same error message. `select
cast(table1.company_id__c as bigint),
table1.casenumber
FROM table2
Left Join table1 on table2.accountid= table1.id
where table1.company_id__c in (
select 
cast(product_A_ID as bigint) as ID2
from table3
where
filter_1='Yes'
and product_A_ID is not null
UNION
select 
cast(product_B_ID as bigint) as ID2
from table3
where
filter_1='Yes'
and product_B_ID is not null)
and table1.country__c='UK'
and table2.createddate between '2020-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'`

Comment: please check the edited answer and see if it works

Comment: no luck, i think there is something going on with table1.company_id__c field. I am going to look closer next week. Thanks for the quick response though.